# build/app.js not found error 404 with react + SF6 using docker

Tags: reactjs, docker, build, http-status-code-404, symfony6

I am a beginner in react and I need some help to find out why my browser is not able to reach : `public/build/app.js`. and display a `<h1>Hello world</h1>`

I am using Symfony 6.3 skeleton and added `symfony/webpack-encore-bundle` + `symfony/twig-bundle`.
I've also install react with :

```
npm i
npm run build
npm i react react-DOM
```

I have this code structure :

```
+ app
|_____+assets
      |________+react
               |______ index.js
      |________+styles
               |______ styles.scss
|____ public
      |______ index.php
      |______ build
              |_____ app.js (and others files)`
```

Those are my configurations files :

./docker-compose.yaml :

```
version:  '3.8'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.23.3-alpine
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - './app/public/:/var/www/app'
      - './docker/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro'
    ports:
      - '${NGINX_PORT}:80'
    depends_on:
      - php

  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/php/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - './app/:/var/www/app'
    restart: on-failure
    env_file:
      - .env
    user: ${LOCAL_USER}
```

docker/php/Dockerfile :

```
FROM composer:2.4.2 as composer

##################################

FROM php:8.1-fpm-alpine3.16

RUN apk add --no-cache \
    bash=~5.1 \
    icu-dev=~71.1 \
    make

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/app/ \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual=.build-deps \
        autoconf=~2.71 \
        g++=~11.2 \
    && docker-php-ext-configure intl \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j"$(nproc)" intl pdo_mysql \
    && apk del .build-deps

WORKDIR /var/www/app

COPY ../../app/composer.json /var/www/app/composer.json
COPY ../../app/composer.lock /var/www/app/composer.lock

RUN PATH=$PATH:/var/www/app/vendor/bin:bin

COPY --from=composer /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

RUN composer install --no-scripts

COPY ../../app/ /var/www/app/

RUN chown -R 1000:1000 /var/www/app/
USER 1000:1000
`

docker/nginx/default.conf :
`server {
    server_name my-project.local www.my-project.local;
    root /var/www/app/public;

    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
}
```

app/webpack.config.js :

```
if (!Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()) {
    Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev');
}

Encore
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    .setPublicPath('/build')

    /*
     * ENTRY CONFIG
     *
     * Each entry will result in one JavaScript file (e.g. index.js)
     * and one CSS file (e.g. styles.scss) if your JavaScript imports CSS.
     */
    .addEntry('app', './assets/react/index.js')
    .addStyleEntry('styles', './assets/styles/styles.scss')
    .splitEntryChunks()
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())
    .configureBabelPresetEnv((config) => {
        config.useBuiltIns = 'usage';
        config.corejs = '3.23';
    })

    // enables Sass/SCSS support
    .enableSassLoader()

    // uncomment if you use React
    .enableReactPreset()
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

As you can see, my nginx default.conf root is in `/var/www/app/public` and it's ok for me because I can find in my docker php container that `/var/www/app/public/build/app.js` exists.

Can someone can explain to me why nginx can't display my Hello world with react please ?

I have tried to change my docker-compose.yaml to point in `/var/www/app/public` instead of `/var/www/app` with no success.

Answer (score 0):

I have fix it by edit my `docker-compose.yaml`

there were a "/public" missing in my nginx volume.
I have changed this line :

```
- './app/public/:/var/www/app'
```

by :

```
- './app/public/:/var/www/app/public'
```

rebuild everything and now it's working !